# Does the text from a response object does not work well with regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-requests

I'm running into a strange bug where I get the text of a MIB file using the `requests` library and regex doesn't want to work with it initially. I'm trying to replace blank lines with nothing.

This code is finding what I'm trying to replace correctly:

```
mib = r.text
blanklines = re.compile(r'\n+\s', re.DOTALL)
for line in blanklines.finditer(mib):
    ...
```

This code is NOT doing any modifications to the string:

```
mib = r.text
blanklines = re.compile(r'\n+\s', re.DOTALL)
mib = blanklines.sub('\n', mib)
```

This code IS modifying the string exactly like I want it to:

```
mib = r.text
with open('rtext.txt', 'w') as tfile:
    tfile.write(mib)
    
with open('rtext.txt','r') as tfile:
    mib = tfile.read()
    
blanklines = re.compile(r'\n+\s', re.DOTALL)
mib = blanklines.sub('\n', mib)
```

I don't guess it's terrible to use this work around but I was hoping somebody here could show me what I was doing wrong. I think it must be with the response text since it works just fine after writing to a file then reading it back.

Comment: Text should be text.  Can you provide an example of `mib`? enough lines to reproduce the problem and test solutions?

Comment: Wild guess: the text you receive has something other than `\n` as the line endings (`\r\n`, perhaps); writing to and reading from a text file is normalizing that to `\n`.

Comment: Maybe what you're thinking is text has other markup? You should include a sample of what you are running your regex on.

Comment: A simple way to detect blank lines is just ```strip()``` them and see if the result is ```Null```. There is no need for regex doing that.

Comment: Do you use the standard re module or the custom regex module?

Comment: Parsing a MIB using regex will be a long slog. Try https://github.com/etingof/pysmi/

Comment: Ooh that \r\n looks familiar. I'll check back in Monday thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented the response had quite a few line breaks that were written as \r\n and I just overlooked them.
Making one change `mib = r.text.replace('\r', '')` fixed the whole problem for me.

And I'm not necessarily trying to parse the entire MIB file so what I have working at this point is going to work for me. I'm really just checking a pcapng file for traps and if we don't have the OID info stored grabbing it from a repo at [circitor.fr/Mibs](http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Mibs.php).

Also if someone has a better repo than that I'd appreciate it because it can be pretty slow.